# Scrape googlemaps location to get lat lon from a website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape this page "https://www.yaencontre.com/alquiler/pisos/barcelona" to get the price, latitude and longitude from every apartment.

I'm able to get the price, but not the latitude and longitude.

Here's my attempt

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env python3
import scrapy
from scraping.items import fields
import pandas as pd
import re

n = 'barcelona'
list_of_urls = []
for i in range(1,2):
    url = 'https://www.yaencontre.com/alquiler/pisos/barcelona/pag-{}'.format(i)
    to_append = [url]
    for j in to_append:
        list_of_urls.append(j)

class scraperApp(scrapy.Spider):
    name = n
    start_urls = list_of_urls
    
    def parse(self,response):
        for href in response.xpath("//a[@class= 'd-ellipsis']/@href"):
            u = 'https://www.yaencontre.com'+ href.extract()    
            print(u)
            yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)                 

    def parse_dir_contents(self,response):
        if(response):         
            
            item = fields() 
            item['vivienda'] = n
            item['price'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='price-wrapper mb-sm']/span").extract_first()
            item['lat'] = response.xpath ('substring-after(substring-before(//img[@class="d-block"]/@src,"%2C"),"=")').extract()
            item['lon'] = response.xpath ('substring-after(substring-before(//img[@class="d-block"]/@src,"&zoom"),"%2C")*1').extract()
            print(item)
            yield item  
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is dynamically loaded by JavaScript from hidden API as `GET` method. So you can easily grab your required data from API response. Below is given working solution as an example.

```
import scrapy
import json
 
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
       
    headers = {
        'USER_AGENT' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        }
   
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://api.yaencontre.com/v3/searchmap?family=FLAT&lang=es&latMax=45.58873524958013&latMin=37.00876645649905&location=barcelona&lonMax=7.707878748840145&lonMin=-11.628058751159855&operation=RENT&orderBy=RELEVANCE&size=200",
            callback= self.parse,
            method= "GET",
            headers= self.headers

        )
    def parse(self, response):
      
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        res = json_response["result"]["items"]
        for item in res:
            yield {
                'lat': item['lat'],
                'lot': item['lon'],
                'price': item['price']
            }
```

**Output:**

```
{'lat': 41.388501578993406, 'lon': 2.1665850093524353, 'price': 4800}
2023-03-22 00:30:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://api.yaencontre.com/v3/searchmap?family=FLAT&lang=es&latMax=45.58873524958013&latMin=37.00876645649905&location=barcelona&lonMax=7.707878748840145&lonMin=-11.628058751159855&operation=RENT&orderBy=RELEVANCE&size=200>
{'lat': 41.39807929851551, 'lon': 2.1822061506785406, 'price': 1890}
2023-03-22 00:30:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://api.yaencontre.com/v3/searchmap?family=FLAT&lang=es&latMax=45.58873524958013&latMin=37.00876645649905&location=barcelona&lonMax=7.707878748840145&lonMin=-11.628058751159855&operation=RENT&orderBy=RELEVANCE&size=200>
{'lat': 41.380495743458205, 'lon': 2.1555876168586092, 'price': 2650}
2023-03-22 00:30:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://api.yaencontre.com/v3/searchmap?family=FLAT&lang=es&latMax=45.58873524958013&latMin=37.00876645649905&location=barcelona&lonMax=7.707878748840145&lonMin=-11.628058751159855&operation=RENT&orderBy=RELEVANCE&size=200>
{'lat': 41.38348724393205, 'lon': 2.1584030638883083, 'price': 2600}
2023-03-22 00:30:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://api.yaencontre.com/v3/searchmap?family=FLAT&lang=es&latMax=45.58873524958013&latMin=37.00876645649905&location=barcelona&lonMax=7.707878748840145&lonMin=-11.628058751159855&operation=RENT&orderBy=RELEVANCE&size=200>
{'lat': 41.37912095360161, 'lon': 2.1722173322787586, 'price': 2990}
2023-03-22 00:30:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-03-22 00:30:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 538,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 135736,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.20321,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 21, 18, 30, 25, 752063),
 'item_scraped_count': 200
```

... so on